Need some clarification on the rule: P(A and B) = P(A)P(B) when checking for independence of events.
I am having little trouble understanding what exactly are the events of P(A) and P(B) when proving independence.
I made an example to show this:
We have a bag with 3 balls: 2 red and 1 blue. If we pick a red ball, we do not replace it. if we pick a blue ball then we do replace it. Are the events of first picking a red ball and then a blue ball independent?
Let event A = picking a red ball first
Let event B = picking a blue ball second
Question: When we use the rule: The events A and B are independent if and only if $P(A \textrm{ and }B) = P(B)P(A)$, does P(B) mean P(picking blue ball) where we use the initial odds i.e. $P($picking blue ball$) = \frac{1}{3}$ or does it mean exactly P(picking a blue ball second), where the odds would be $\frac{4}{27}$?
Example 1(where P(picking blue ball))
$P(A) = \frac{2}{3}$
$P(B) = \frac{1}{3}$
$P(A \textrm{ and }B) = P(B|A)P(A) = \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{2}{3} = \frac{1}{3}$
And $P(A)P(B) = \frac{2}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{3} = \frac{2}{9}$
Using the rule to test for independence, The events A and B are independent if and only if $P(A \textrm{ and }B) = P(B)P(A)$.
Thus $P(A \textrm{ and }B) = \frac{1}{3} \neq \frac{2}{9} = P(B)P(A)$
Thus we can conclude that the events are dependent
Example 2(where P(picking a blue ball second))
$P(A) = \frac{2}{3}$
$P(B) = P(B|A)P(A) + P(B|\textrm{ not } A)P(\textrm{ not }A) = \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{2}{3}+\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{3} = \frac{4}{9}$
$P(A \textrm{ and }B) = P(B|A)P(A) = \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{2}{3} = \frac{1}{3}$
And $P(A)P(B) = \frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{4}{9} = \frac{4}{27}$
Using the rule to test for indepedence, The events A and B are independent if and only if $P(A \textrm{ and }B) = P(B)P(A)$.
Thus $P(A \textrm{ and }B) = \frac{1}{3} \neq \frac{4}{27} = P(B)P(A)$
Thus we can conclude that the events are dependent
Which is actually the correct way? I can't seem to find clear information on this and would greatly appreciate you advice.
Here are some diagrams: first pic is the tree diagram of the probabilities, and the second is all possible outcomes


It's down to you do decide what the descriptions of the events in your example mean. Is it actually your example or did you get it from some other source?

@RobArthan It is my made up example. I guess I am wanting to know that we use P(picking blue ball second) was exactly what we use and that it was not "just" some words where we use P(picking blue ball) as if it was unaffected by previous actions and use the initial odds

Think about the sample space $\Omega = {RR, RB, BR, BB}$. For any event, you should be able to say exactly which subset of $\Omega$ corresponds to that event.  eg. picking red ball first is ${RR, RB}$. Only once you have established this (what exactly the events are) can you think about whether they are independent.

If $B$ is the event of picking a blue ball second, then $P(B)$ is the marginal probability of picking a blue ball second, which is not necessarily the probability of picking a blue ball first, and is not in this particular example.
Looking at the different was the first two balls can be picked in order:

you have $P(A)=P(Red\,Red)+P(Red\,Blue) = \frac23\times \frac12 + \frac23\times \frac12 = \frac13+\frac13 = \frac23$
you have $P(B)=P(Red\,Blue)+P(Blue\,Blue) = \frac23\times \frac12  + \frac13\times \frac13 = \frac13+\frac19= \frac49$
so $P(A) P(B) =\frac23 \times \frac4{9}=\frac{8}{27}$
while  $P(A \text{ and }B) = P(Red\,Blue) = \frac23\times \frac12 =\frac13$
and, since $P(A) P(B) \not =P(A \text{ and }B)$, you can say $A$ and $B$ are not independent

This is intuitively obvious, since the  colour of the ball you pick first affects the probabilities for the different colours of the ball you might pick second.

Thank you for your answer. I was getting confused for: "drawing a heart, do not replace the card, then draw another heart" then they would have P(A) = 1/4, P(B)=1/4 and P(A and B) = 1/412/51 = 1/17. Thus as 1/16 != 1/17, thus dependent. From this it looks like P(B) uses initial odds.  I know if you follow the Tree P(H second) = P(H,H)+P(not H, H) = 1/412/51 + 3/4*13/51 = 1/4, so your answer holds, but they never ever show that they are actually doing it this way - or am I missing something?

$A$ and $B$ are the events that you want to know whether they are independent.  In this case, although the wording of the question could be a bit clearer, the only interpretation that makes sense to me is that  $A$ is the event "the first ball picked is red"  and $B$ is the event "the second ball picked is blue".  You certainly should not take $P(B)$ to be the probability that the first ball picked is blue.

Thank you for your answer, I just wanted to confirm that we used P(picking blue ball second) was exactly what we use and that it was not "just" some words where we use P(picking blue ball) as if it was unaffected by previous actions.

In general, you should be as specific as possible when describing an event.  Include all relevant details. You can't just say "picking blue ball" when the circumstances in which that blue ball is to be picked may affect the probability.
